# how to connect two reactjs pages and display same data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

this is my react code where I send data to my server and getting result on this page..!actully I have two pages with same code  and I just want connect those two pages. I want when someone click(Poll) on one page the result will also shown on second page.. so how can I connect 2 pages ..? please help

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";
import "../../styles.scss";
import { isAutheticated } from "../../auth/helper/index";
import { getPolls, postPoll } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import axios from "axios";
import { API } from "../../backend";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const FullPoll = () => {
  const userId = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().user._id;
  const [polls, setPoll] = useState([]);
  const [error, seterror] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    loadPoll();
  }, [polls]);

  const loadPoll = () => {
    getPolls().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        seterror(data.error);
      } else {
        setPoll(data.reverse());
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  const handalchange = async (pollId, userId, answer) => {
    if (userId === false || 0) {
      history.push("/signin");
    } else {
      console.log(pollId);
      console.log(userId); // getting
      console.log(answer); // getting
      await axios
        .post(`${API}/vote/${pollId}`, { userId, answer })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            seterror(data.error);
            console.log(data.error);
          } else {
            loadPoll();
            // console.log(data);
          }
        });
    }
  };

  const errorMessage = () => {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <div className="">
          <div
            className="alert alert-danger"
            style={{ display: error ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            {error}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="container my-5">
        <h1 className="blog_heading my-3">Poll's of the Day</h1>
        <div className="row">
          {errorMessage()}
          {polls.reverse().map((poll, index) => (
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-12 gy-3">
              <div className="card poll_card" key={index}>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <Poll
                    question={poll.question}
                    answers={Object.keys(poll.options).map((key) => {
                      return {
                        option: key,
                        votes: poll.options[key].length,
                      };
                    })}
                    onVote={
                      (answer) =>
                        handalchange(
                          poll._id,
                          userId,
                          answer,
                          console.log(answer)
                        ) // getting vote
                    }
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FullPoll;
```

This is a frontend result I am getting ..!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z1v5.png)
this my second page where I am also getting result with same code ...!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";
import "../../styles.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAutheticated } from "../../auth/helper/index";
import { getPolls, postPoll } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import axios from "axios";
import { API } from "../../backend";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const MainPoll = () => {
  const userId = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().user._id;
  const [polls, setPoll] = useState([]);
  const [error, seterror] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    loadPoll();
  }, [polls]);

  const loadPoll = () => {
    getPolls().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        seterror(data.error);
      } else {
        setPoll(data.reverse());
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  const handalchange = async (pollId, userId, answer) => {
    if (userId === false || 0) {
      history.push("/signin");
    } else {
      console.log(pollId);
      console.log(userId); // getting
      console.log(answer); // getting
      await axios
        .post(`${API}/vote/${pollId}`, { userId, answer })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            seterror(data.error);
            console.log(data.error);
          } else {
            loadPoll();
            // console.log(data);
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="container ">
        <h1 className="blog_heading">Poll's of the Day</h1>
        <div className="row PollsHeight">
          {polls.reverse().map((poll, index) => (
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-12 gy-3">
              <div className="card poll_card" key={index}>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <Poll
                    question={poll.question}
                    answers={Object.keys(poll.options).map((key) => {
                      return {
                        option: key,
                        votes: poll.options[key].length,
                      };
                    })}
                    onVote={
                      (answer) =>
                        handalchange(
                          poll._id,
                          userId,
                          answer,
                          console.log(answer)
                        ) // getting vote
                    }
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Link to="/allpolls" className="ForMorebtn container">
          For More
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainPoll;
```

this is my frontend result of second page !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MdYG.png)
I just want to connect both page's like if I vote on first page the result will  refelect on second page to..!not just on one page..!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with window.localStorage.

Something like when you select the value save the option and the store.

```
localStorage.setItem('option', 'option1');
```

And then when you show the select you can validate if the storage is empty or have some value with:

```
const cat = localStorage.getItem('option');
```

And depending on the option you can show the value.

You can also do it with Redux it would be a bit more complex.

You can read more about Window.Localstorage here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: thank you! but can you show me with code..!actully I don't understand where i can change my code @Carlos